# I want to install pyqt5(Python 3.4) on Travis-ci, but it doesn't work

Tags: pyqt5, travis-ci, python-3.4

I want to install pyqt5 on travis-ci but it doesn't work.

I already tried many ways like pip install pyqt5 and I don't know how to fix this error: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)"

```
language: python

python:
  - "3.4"
install:
 - pip install cx_freeze==4.3.3
 - pip install libyaz0
 - pip install sarclib
 - pip install pyqt5
```

log: https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/529770981/log.txt

Comment: could you include the `.travis.yml` and a link to the full error log?

Comment: I hope that will help you to fix the error

Comment: is there a link to the log with the full install history?

Comment: I added the log file

Answer (score 0):

try adding this block to your `.travis.yml`

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: @NintendoCustom edited to use the `apt` version of `pyqt5`